# Unable to setup libGDX with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I cannot seem to setup libGDX with IntelliJ. Everything goes smoothly until I attempt to open the build.gradle file. Then, IntelliJ says Could not find lwjgl-glfw-3.3.2-natives-linux.jar (org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:3.3.2).

I believe that the problem is that it is attempting to run as if it was on Linux, I am using Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The solution was to comment out the "mavenlocal()" lines.

Comment: kudos on finding the answer! To make it more useful you should also include the code you were trying to use on the question so that the lines you are referencing on your response are easily found on the same post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).